# Can't publish with aws-iot-device-sdk, but can subscribe

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

My mqtt client is unable to publish to messages to AWS, but is able to receive them. The following code works to subscribe to the mqtt Client, and print messages received to the console.

```
  if (Object.keys(cred).length !== 0) { //if temp creds exist, create mqtt client
    const mqttClient = AWSIoTData.device({
      region: awsConfig.region,
      host: awsConfig.mqttEndpoint,
      clientId: awsConfig.clientId,
      protocol: "wss",
      maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
      debug: false,
      accessKeyId: String(cred.AccessKeyId),
      secretKey: String(cred.SecretAccessKey),
      sessionToken: String(cred.SessionToken),
    });

    mqttClient.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("mqttClient connected");
      mqttClient.subscribe("mg/autogenstart/fromDevice");
    });
    mqttClient.on("message", (topic, payload) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(payload.toString()));
    });
```

However, the following code does not work to publish to the client on connect.

```
  if (Object.keys(cred).length !== 0) { //if temp creds exist, create mqtt client
    const mqttClient = AWSIoTData.device({
      region: awsConfig.region,
      host: awsConfig.mqttEndpoint,
      clientId: awsConfig.clientId,
      protocol: "wss",
      maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
      debug: false,
      accessKeyId: String(cred.AccessKeyId),
      secretKey: String(cred.SecretAccessKey),
      sessionToken: String(cred.SessionToken),
    });

    mqttClient.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("mqttClient connected");
      mqttClient.publish(
        "mg/autogenstart/toDevice",
        JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1 })
      );
    });
```

Any ideas why? I've tried using the same topic, and creating an empty rule in IoT Core for mg/autogenstart/toDevice.

Comment: Can you share the policy that is attached to the credentials that you're using to connect to the MQTT broker?

Comment: It has awsiot full access. {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: the pub and sub topic in your code doesn't look the same, try  mqttClient.subscribe("mg/autogenstart/toDevice");

Comment: The subscribing works but publishing doesn't. I tried "mg/autogenstart/fromDevice" for publishing as well :/

Comment: Do you get an error message, or does simply nothing happen? I don't know the library you're using, but my guess is that the publish is an asynchronous action? In that case, your application could have exited before the action actually took place, since you're not waiting for the action to be completed. But it's a guess, since we have no information on the library you're using to connect.

Comment: Nope, I don't get an error message. Async-await on the publish function didn't work

Comment: might try "debug: true" for verbose logging

Comment: Where can I enter that parameter?

Comment: its option when you create AWSIoTData.device(), it’s set to false in you code, if you change to true that might give you more info on the error

Comment: I added debug=true and nothing looks wrong at first glance. I'm getting Canonical request: GET \mqtt, hashed canonical request, string to sign, signing key, signature, url. What should I look for?